# CORS issue while trying to access https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token' to "acquireTokenOnBehalfOf" from localhost & app domains

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-teams, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-graph-api

We are enabling SSO for our Teams App using the below documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/tab-sso-graph-api?tabs=nodejs#configure-code-to-fetch-access-token-using-msal

This is the code that is used to acquire a token using MSAL:

```
msalClient.acquireTokenOnBehalfOf({
    authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tid}`,
    oboAssertion: token,
    scopes: scopes,
    skipCache: true
})
```

When we try to acquire token by passing `tenantId` or `common` as authority, the token API is failing because of CORS issue in both local as well as the development environment.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token' from origin *** has been blocked by CORS policy

We have added the domains in expose API during registration.

Is there any other config which is needed to allow requests from other defined origins (`localhost` and other domains)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're using client-side code to get this token - if so, very importantly, you've misunderstood how this works. An 'OnBehalfOf' token call should ONLY be made from a backend server, in which case CORS would not apply. There is 'javascript' code for this because you might have a Node-based backend, NOT because you're meant to use it from in the browser.

The only call you need to make from your front-end code is to

```
microsoftTeams.authentication.getAuthToken()
```

Here's a more detailed answer I've given before - please have a look and also check out the excellent video and blog post I've linked in there: [Problem with getting SSO Auth token from Microsoft Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71705028/problem-with-getting-sso-auth-token-from-microsoft-teams/71705315#71705315)

Comment: Thanks for your response !!
One question, While referring to "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/tab-sso-graph-api?tabs=dotnet" for adding SSO,
I could identify 3 steps
1. To get authtoken using microsoftTeams.authentication.getAuthToken()
2. To exchange this token using OBO flow - ttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/tab-sso-graph-api?tabs=nodejs#configure-code-to-fetch-access-token-using-msal
3. And lastly pass the token from step 2 while making graph api call
Is this understanding correct?

Comment: As per the above steps and this text in documentation "To get the permissions (scopes) needed to make a Graph call, SSO apps must implement a custom web service to exchange the token received from the Teams JavaScript SDK for a token that includes the needed scopes."
I understand that we would have to use OBO and retrieve token to make graph api calls for SSO ? Or is it not needed ?
Also Can you please share the link and video that you mentioned, would be really helpful to understand.

Comment: oh sorry, I forgot to add the link to the other post! Updated now.

Comment: Your steps above are basically correct, but just to be clear, you don't need the OBO or anything like that for "SSO". SSO is just allowing your tab to sign in and authenticate the user, so that your API can for instance verify that the user is who they say they are, that has value by itself. You can't trust the Teams Context for this, it's not safe by itself. But as a NEXT stage, IF you want to call Graph (which it seems you do), then you need to have IMPLEMENTED the SSO first.

Comment: And to answer your second point, yes, to make this all work properly and securely, you should have a backend API in between your tab itself and the Microsoft Graph, where you do the OBO exchange and do the operations to call Graph.

Comment: It's quite a bit to understand, so please let me know as you go if you have any further questions.

Comment: Thanks, I am going though this and will get back in case of further questions.

Comment: great. Good luck with it.